# ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: []

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to build a CNN + Transformer model for Semantic segmentation of cracks given images with their masks in respective directories.
my code :

```
# Convert the data to numpy arrays
images = np.array(images)
masks = np.array(masks)

# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
train_images, test_images, train_masks, test_masks = train_test_split(images, masks, test_size=0.2)


# Define the backbone CNN
backbone = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False)

# Define the input layers for the mask and image
image_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
mask_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 1))

# Define the backbone CNN
backbone = keras.applications.ResNet50V2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

# Define the mask input layer
mask_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 1))
mask_layer = keras.layers.Conv2D(3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(mask_input)

# Pass the image and mask inputs through the backbone CNN
image_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

backbone_output = backbone(image_input)
mask_output = backbone(mask_layer)

# Concatenate the backbone output and mask layer
concatenated_input = keras.layers.Concatenate()([backbone_output, mask_output])

# Apply a dense layer to the concatenated input
dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(concatenated_input)

# Apply a convolutional layer to the dense output
conv_layer = keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_layer)

# Define the model
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[image_input, mask_input], outputs=conv_layer)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_images, train_masks, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_images, test_masks))
```

I am getting error in this line :

```
  62 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
     64 # Train the model
---> 65 model.fit(train_images, train_masks, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_images, test_masks))
```

Error :

```
    ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: []
```

I am new to tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

**Two possible scenarios:**

**Scenario 1.** Assuming your model is correct, your code explains train inputs to model, but labels are not defined; arguments to the fit method are incorrect.

Inputs:

> `train_images`: shape (batch,224,224,3)
>
> `train_masks`: shape (batch,224,224,1)
>
> `test_images`: shape (batch,224,224,3)
>
> `test_masks`: shape (batch,224,224,1)

Output: (should be defined)

> `train_labels`: shape (batch,7,7,1)
>
> `test_labels`: shape (batch,7,7,1)

Corrected code:

```py
# Train the model
# pack inputs in a list and provide as the first argument
# provide your label as the second argument
model.fit([train_images, train_masks], train_labels, epochs=10, validation_data=([test_images, test_masks], test_labels))
```

**Scenario 2.** If your problem is semantic segmentation, images could be inputs and masks could be outputs, right? In that case, your model should take only images as input, but not (images, masks) pair. If this is the case, you have to modify the model architecture; arguments to the fit method are perfect.

Either scenario 1 or scenario 2 may resolve your problem.